# Working with depth order/z-index - duel wielded weapons

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a game with Phaser. Basically there is a player sprite, that walks around and can pickup/hold up to 2 weapons.

I am trying to display one gun *behind* the player sprite, and one gun in *front*.

I can't figure out the best way to display them in their proper depth. I know Phaser is not capable of setting explicit z-index values for sprites. But maybe there is a way to compare each weapons z-index to the player's sprite, then adjust accordingly via `moveUp` or `bringBack`?

Here are the sprites:

```
player.sprite = this.game.add.sprite(500, 500, 'player');
gun1.sprite = this.game.add.sprite(550,525, 'gun');
gun2.sprite = this.game.add.sprite(525,525,'gun');
```

Comment: What's the relation between `player`, `gun1` and `gun2`? Are they separate `GameObject`s?

Comment: @KamenMinkov No, they are just sprites being displayed that overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you pick up a gun, call a function bringToTop();
For example, you want gun1 to be behind a player, and gun2 to be in front of the player.

```
// Call functions
gun1.bringToTop();
player.bringToTop();
gun2.bringToTop();
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you this works perfectly!
Just for anyone who might view this I discovered it's actually `game.world.bringToTop(gun1)`.